# Linked Server View Error

Tags: sql-server

I am getting this error when trying to use a view on a linked server.

```
OLE DB providerr linked server returned data that does not match expected data length for column ' The (maximum) expected data length is 30 while the returned data length is 34.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this on the server where your table and view is located:

sp_refreshview 'viewname'